# R "return()" returning an NA value at the end of a function

Tags: r, function

I am having the following problem in R. This function takes in a vector of numbers that have "[", and "]" at the beginning and end. The goal of the function is to remove the starting and trailing square brackets and return a vector of the numbers. A sample input is "[23, 54, 12, 54, 32, 45, 74, 29]" and the output should be, "23, 54, 12, 54, 32, 45, 74, 29", as a numeric object. Everything works until I try to return the value. The "return(thing)" statement returns NA instead of the vector. I must be missing something. Any thoughts.

```
split_bmi <- function(thing) {

        thing <- as.character(thing)
        thing <- strsplit(thing, "")
        thing <- unlist(thing)
        thing <- thing[c(-1, -length(thing))]
        thing <- capture.output(cat(thing, sep = ""))
        thing <- list(strsplit(thing, ","))
        thing <- as.numeric(thing)
        return(thing)
}
```

Comment: Maybe just `as.numeric(strsplit(gsub("\\[|\\]","",thing),",")[[1]])` would be simpler

Comment: `scan(text = gsub("\\[|\\]|,","",thing))` would also work

Answer (score 4):

`thing` is a list when you pass it to `as.numeric`, but `as.numeric` is not smart enough to look through elements of a list. For instance `as.numeric(list(letters))` produces `NA` with a warning. Try `as.numeric(unlist(thing))`.

@joran's solution is a very good one.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, using the stringr package.

```
library(stringr)
split_bmi <- function(x) {
     x <- str_replace(x, "\\[" , "") %>%
          str_replace("\\]", "") %>%
          str_split(pattern = ",") %>%
          unlist() %>%
          as.numeric()
     return(x)
}
```